# Encontrar el número de observaciones que cumplen una condición en R

Tags: r

Tengo un data frame con dos columnas: una de ellas indica la media y otra, la desviación estándar.

Me gustaría utilizar una función que me indicara aquellas celdas del data frame en las que la desviación estándar se desvía de la media en más de 2.5 puntos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer se llama un subset o subconjunto y en R la forma más directa de hacerlo es usando los corchetes `[ , ]`. La coma del medio en este caso es necesaria porque estás trabajando con un data frame.

Primero vamos a crear unos datos para hacer el test y saber si funciona la solución. Creamos un data frame con 10 filas aleatorias normales con media 0 y desvio estandar 1 que van a ser las "medias" de tus datos. Después otra columna con otros diez números aleatorios similares, a los que sumamos 2.5. De ese modo en algunos casos la diferencia va a ser mayor a 2.5, en otros casos no. Así podremos saber si el filtro condicional funciona.

> En tu ejercicio deberías reemplazarlo por tus datos, que más o menos tendrán esa estructura.

Después vamos a hacer el subset, conservando solo aquellas filas del data frame en las que se cumple la condición según la cuál la diferencia (resta) entre la media y el desvio es mayor a 2.5.

Por último, como querías saber en cuantos casos se cumplía la condición, vamos a ver cuantas filas quedan en el data frame final.

```
set.seed(2018)  #Para resultados reproducibles              
df <- data.frame(media = rnorm(10, 0, 1), 
                 desvest = rnorm(10, 0, 1) + 2.5)

desvio_mayor <- df[df$desvest-df$media>2.5, ]  #Es muy importante esta coma para indicar que queremos operar por filas
nrow(desvio_mayor)
```

Si te interesa saber como funcionan los corchetes en este caso, podrías pasar directamente en consola `df$desvest-df$media > 2.5`. Verás que sale un vector lógico con valores `TRUE` y `FALSE` del mismo largo que los vectores que secompararon. Los corchetes usan ese vector lógico para hacer su trabajo. Cuando ven que `TRUE` conservan la fila, cuando ven que `FALSE` la descartan. Al final quedan solamente las que cumplen la condición.